# Is there a way to generate sonar generic test execution report from Ruby Rspec unit test execution result on my local machine for a ruby project?

Tags: ruby, rubygems, sonarqube

Since Sonarqube doesn't support ruby test execution report by default, i need a way to manually generate the generic test execution report that Sonarqube will accept, on my local machine during execution of the rspec unit tests.   The xml report can be given as input during the execution of sonar-scanner .

Comment: Do you have code to generate the report? You can call whatever code you want from tests.

Comment: Yes ,I have a sample ruby file containing test cases and i have successfully generated code coverage report for the program using Simplecov was accepted by sonar but i don't seem to find anything similar to that for the unit test execution report needed for sonar.I hope that was the question that you asked.

Comment: I have no idea what is the format Sonar needs. I added the Sonarkube tag to the question. If you know where there are docs for it, it would be useful to link them in the question.

Comment: https://docs.sonarqube.org/latest/analysis/generic-test/ This is the link for the format the sonar will accept , listed under generic execution.